# Shell script to create directories and files from a list of file names

Tags: list, shell, touch, directory, mkdir

I'm (still) not a shell-wizard, but I'm trying to find a way to create directories and files from a list of file names.

Let's take this source file (`source.txt`) as an example:

```
README.md
foo/index.html

  foo/bar/README.md
foo/bar/index.html

foo/baz/README.md
```

I'll use this command to remove empty lines and trim useless spaces:

```
$ more source.txt | sed '/^$/d;s/^ *//;s/ *$//'
```

It will give me this list:

```
README.md
foo/index.html
foo/bar/README.md
foo/bar/index.html
foo/baz/README.md
```

Now I'm trying to loop on every line and create the related file (it it doesn't already exists), with it's parents directories.

How could I do this?
Ideally, I would put this script in an alias to quickly use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, posting a question brings me to the end of the problem...

I came to a satisfying solution, using `dirname` and `basename` in a `for .. in` loop:

```
for i in `cat source.txt | sed '/^$/d;s/^ *//;s/ *$//'`; 
  do mkdir -p `dirname $i`; 
     touch `echo $(dirname $i)$(echo "/")$(basename $i)`; 
  done
```

This one-line command will:

- read the file names list
- create directories
- create empty files in their own directory